Flask MySQL database session best practice – resolve Broken Pipe Error
My question for this post: Is using and relying on before_request and after_request to handle opening and closing database sessions ok or just a mess?
Background
I have a Python Flask Website, a different Flask app that is the API, and a service Python app that the API can call when needed that connect to the same MySQL database. They all use SQLAlchemy to communicate with the same MySQL database.
Every morning, I find a similar Broken Pipe Error which prevents the first user for the day from logging in right away. They will need to try a few times to rollback and close the session. This is the problem I am ultimately trying to resolve.
My approach has been, instead of trying to find the loose end database session, I thought I could cut off an expiring database session by using the before_request decorator to instantiate a db session. Then after_request decorator to close the session after each request.
This doesn’t seem to be working. I have not prevented Broken Pipe errors.
Should I just create a database session when I need it and close it? Then if I find Broken Pipe error try to find the source of the problem.
Diagram of my overall structure simplified

full size image here
If someone has a GitHub repo that follows some best practices with Flask and SQLAlchemay (using MySQL and no Flask-SQLAlchemy) that would also be helpful.
Reserach
I have tried asking ChatGPT but this is too general of a question and not getting helpful answers. Any advice greatly appreciated.
Here are two questions that get close to what I am asking:

how to use after_request in flask to close database connection and python?
Best practices for persistent database connections in Python when using Flask

It seems in (#1) someone else is doing what I am doing. Is this a good way to handle database sessions? Would creating a database session and closing it in the routes each time be uncommon and a lot more work?

First, you are using a blueprint and you need to use before_app_request to register your function for every request instead of only blueprint requests. Second, instead of using after_request you are supposed to use teardown_request to close any resources you have, because after_request doesn't run when there's an exception. Using both of these decorators are fine for resource management per request. Your problem description does not include any tracebacks or logs, so I'm not sure what your issue is exactly.

It's been 2 days no Broken Pipe error.
Yes, teardown_request was what I should have been using. Also, making these functions app wide by registering them in my init.py file at the root of my package was an improvement. The other thing I added was pool_recycle parameter to my create_engine(). If anyone wants to see more details on my changes see here: https://www.reddit.com/r/flask/comments/1cqus6q/flask_mysql_database_session_best_practice/
Thanks @Bck!
